# Boiling point of liquids

Tags: physical-chemistry, phase

If we can have liquid - vapour equilibrium at any temperature what is the 'point' behind boiling point.Boiling point is just a special case of liquid - vapour equilibrium where partial pressure equals atmospheric pressure.Why is it told in my textbook that boiling point is where the liquid and vapour coexist. At any temperature we can have liquid and vapour in equilibrium.

During boiling process when vapourisation take place from the bulk of the liquid does that increase the vapour composition which alters the equilibrium constant without the change in temperature?..

If we look at the phase diagram boiling point lies on phase boundary between liquid and gas ...so does that mean boiling point is when liquid and gas coexist..

Comment: Well, yes, it means exactly that.

Comment: "boiling line" might be a more accurate term, but requires at least two variables, making it very hard to compare. Strictly speaking the same is true for melting, only the pressure dependence is less noticeable there.

Comment: Boiling liquid is not in equilibrium.

Comment: @Poutnik  It is, just not a nice spatially homogeneous or even static equillibrium. And its temperature needs to be above the boiling point, by a small but finite difference.

Comment: To be more precise, boiling is not thermodynamic equilibrium, but it is kind of dynamic equilibrium. There is need of continuous providing of thermal energy and eventually even liquid.

Comment: Additionally, the *boiling line" is primarily the evaporation line, as boiling is just a special mode of evaporation. At this line, liquid and gas can coexist with zero net mass transfer between phases.

Comment: At the boiling point, there is an equilibrium between pure vapor and pure liquid phase (at a certain pressure). A substance in the (pure) liquid phase can also be at equilibrium with a mixture of inert gas and that substance in the vapor phase (so the partial pressure of the substance would be lower than the total pressure). This happens at temperatures below the boiling point. These are two different scenarios (either pure gas phase or mixture in the gas phase).

Answer (score 4):

Liquid and vapour can coexist at many combinations of temperature and pressure. But for most of them they are not in thermodynamic quilibrium.

For a given temperuture, there is only one (vapour partial ) pressure value with both phases in equilibrium.

For a given vapour partial  pressure, there is only one temperature value with both phases in equilibrium.

This temperature is also the liquid boiling point at the given external ( total ) pressure.

Standard boiling point is then temperature, when vapour partial pressure is equal external pressure 1 atm.

Note that boiling is not state of thermodynamic equilibrium, as there is net change of phase mass and thermal energy.

If partial pressure is higher than the equilibrium pressure for given temperature, the vapour condensates until the pressure reaches the liquid-vapour equilibrium curve of the phase diagram.

If partial pressure is lower than the equilibrium pressure for given temperature, the liquid evaporates until the pressure reaches the liquid-vapour equilibrium curve of the phase diagram.

If total pressure is lower than the vapour pressure for given temperature, the liquid boils until the total pressure reaches the saturated  vapour pressure.

Comment: But since we have vapour pressure for given liquid at different temperature does that constant vapour pressure defines equilibrium point at those temperature

Comment: No, the equilibrium vapour pressure is fully determined by temperature. If vapour pressure is lower than the equilibrium pressure, liquid evaporates. If higher, then vapour condensates. If total pressure is lower, liquid boils.

Comment: For all the use of *equilibrium pressure* I think you missed the most important part. By definition a liquid is at the *boiling point* when the vapor pressure equals the ambient pressure, whatever that happens to be.  The *standard boiling point* is when the vapor pressure equals 1 atmosphere.  The choice of 1 atmosphere is a completely arbitrary choice made by humans based on a collective experience. On the planet "Tatooine" for example the standard pressure would be different.

Comment: I have just omitted it as implicitly known but it is there.

Comment: Boiling point is when phase transition takes place so ,is it correct to say its the point when gas and liquid is in equilibrium rather than telling liquid and vapour is in equilibrium.

Comment: Equilibrium is when there is no net change in the phase amount and phases can coexist for unlimited time. That is not the case for boiling. If the liquid is kept in a closed volume and stops boiling when the pressure raises enough, then after this moment it is close to equilibrium.